# What is the best way to get the first few post from WordPress in different divs using a loop?

Tags: php, loop, jquery, html

I got the first post using the loop but I can't get the second post.

I would  like every post to be in a different div but the same style as the first post.
To do this, I would probably need to create more loops.
I want to do this so I can get a slide show with div's using jquery.

The first part of the loop selects the first image in a post and the second part of the loop removes the image from the text and shows the text using the WordPress format.

You can find an example here:

http://www.volunteeringnews.com/index2.php

Thanks you very much!

```
<div class="nto">
        <div class="natt">

            <?php
            $attachments = get_children(
                array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_parent' => $post->ID
                ));
            if(count($attachments) > 0) { ?>
                <?php
                    $attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order'));
                    if ( ! is_array($attachments) ) continue;
                    $count = count($attachments);
                    $first_attachment = array_shift($attachments);
                    ?>
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID, 'medium'); ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="/img/body/facebook_logo.gif">
                <?php } ?>

        </div>

<!--First post text-->

    <div class ="nfh">

        <?php

            //Show first post only
        add_filter('the_content', 'narga_excerpts');
            query_posts('showposts=1');
            $ids = array();
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $ids[] = get_the_ID();
            //Add remove filter first image
            function remove_first_image ($content) {
            $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
            return $content;}
            add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
            //Get post format               
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            //Remove remove filter first image
            remove_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_first_image' );
            remove_filter( 'the_content', 'narga_excerpts' );


            endwhile;
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the loop. I removed your comments and added some for clarification.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {

    // Do first post.

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'narga_excerpts' );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_first_image' );

    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );


    // Do remaining posts.

    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'narga_excerpts' );
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_first_image' );

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    }
}
?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

// Add remove filter first image.
function remove_first_image( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', $content, 1 );
}
```

You didn't give enough details on the `<div>`s you want to wrap the posts with, so I left that part off. I also removed the function definition in the loop. Place your functions at the bottom of the file.